# Kendo LineChart set zoom from js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

Anybody know how to set zoom level for Kendo line chart from js code?
I use asp .net mvc and my chart have this settings

```
.Pannable(p => p.Lock(ChartAxisLock.Y))
.Zoomable(z => z.Mousewheel(m => m.Lock(ChartAxisLock.Y)).Selection(s => s.Lock(ChartAxisLock.Y)))
```

and when I scroll up\down mouse chart change zoom. By I need to set default zoom when data loaded into chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the categoryAxis Min and Max to the limits of the desired zoom.

```
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        .Min(0)
        .Max(10)
    )
```

See this demo which starts zoomed in to the first 10 items:  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/bar-charts/pan-and-zoom